# jqPlot line chart's pointlabels are shown in wrong place

Tags: jqplot, linechart

I am working with jqPlot's Line chart where data should be displayed for last 12 months. If current month is September then X axis will show 2012 August till 2013 September. However, I have data starting from January 2013. Therefore the lines will start from the middle of the chart till the most recent available month's data.

**Problem**: Lines are started from the correct position, but the pointables have not moved accordingly. Although the lines show correctly the pointables are shown from beginning of the chart.

[image]

**Question**: How can I move the pointables which should be on the dots instead?

**Update**: Seems line known issue in jqPlot ([issue log](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/780/pointlabels-show-at-wrong-location-when))

```
var json= {    
        title: '' 
        ,stackSeries: false   
        ,captureRightClick: true    
        ,seriesDefaults:{      
            //renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer      
            rendererOptions: {                            
                highlightMouseDown: true                             
            }      
            ,pointLabels: {
                show: true
                ,formatString: '%.1f'
                ,seriesLabelIndex:null
                ,hideZeros:true
            }
            ,markerOptions: {
                show: true,    

                style: 'filledCircle',  
            }  
        }  
            ,series: [
                {label: 'A', color:'#FDC12E'}
                ,{label: 'B', color:'#C9198D'}
                ,{label: 'C', color:'#56B9F9'}
                ,{label: 'D', color: '#F1683C'}
                                    ,{label: 'E', color: '#000000'}
            ]

            ,axes: {      
                xaxis: {          
                    tickOptions:{angle:-45}
                    ,tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                    ,renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                    ,ticks: []
                },      
                yaxis: {   
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                    ,padMin: 0
                    ,pad: 1.05
                    ,min: 0
                    ,tickOptions:{formatString: '%.0f'},
                } 
            }    
            ,legend: {
                show: true 
                ,location: 's'
                ,placement: 'outsideGrid'
            }
            ,highlighter:{
                show: true
                ,tooltipLocation: 's'
                ,yvalues: 2
                ,bringSeriesToFront:true
                ,showMarker:false
                ,tooltipAxes: 'y'
                ,formatString: "%n%s"
            }
            ,cursor:{
                show: true
                ,zoom:true
                ,showTooltip:false
                ,constrainZoomTo: 'y'
            }
            ,grid:{
                background: '#f8f8f8'
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround until jqPlot fixes their bug. Apparently adding `breakOnNull: true` to `seriesDefaults` fixes the issue. This can be used either for `pointLabels` or for `highlighter` in JSON part.

Comment: Otherwise you can specify min and/or max value for xaxis : See [second example here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php)

Comment: I am afraid min/max value did not work because of null value.

Comment: So you can do a pre-processing before plotting your graph where you scan data and keep min and max values except null ones